# Trying get list of other calendar events from my calendar using PHP

Tags: calendar

Following code is working for Returns events on the specified calendar using
Google Calendar Service class but I want to get events list of other Google calendar through my calendar means that I created calendar from my Google calendar account just I want to list events of that created other Google calendar from my Google calendar.

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');

while(true) {
    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
    }
    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an events page. You want to list your calendars first with the code below.

```
     $calList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

     foreach ($calList['items'] as $calendar){
            echo '<tr><td><a href="events.php?id='.urlencode($calendar['id']).'">'. $calendar['summary'].'</a></td><td>'.$calendar['id'].'</td></tr>';
     }
?>
</table>
```

Then edit your event page and take 'primary' out and substitute it with the google calendar id that you passed it

```
$cal_id = $_GET['id'];

$events = $service->events->listEvents($cal_id);

while(true) {
    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
    }
    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents($cal_id, $optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

that should allow you to see you calendars in the page i provided and your calendar events with the your edited code.

Comment: or you could change 'primary' with the google calendar id gotten in the calendar settings.